# Getting HTTP 412 with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, http, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm writing some CasperJS scripts that allow me to login sites from console. However, when I try to login `https://www.zara.com/us/`, I keep getting HTTP 412 Precondition Failed. I've tried `--ssl-protocol=any` and `--ignore-ssl-erros=true` but it doesn't fix the problem. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps they have a security system that figured out that you are scraping them and breaking their terms of service.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try `--web-security=false`, but I do not think your problem is related to HTTPS. With this simple script, I get a 200 code (even though I run it without any options):

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('https://www.zara.com/us/');

casper.then(function () {
  this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.run();
```

There is most likely something wrong in your code when you fill forms or in the HTTP headers of your request. For the record, here is the description of the 412 error ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/412)):

> The HTTP 412 Precondition Failed client error response code indicates
>   that access to the target resource has been denied. This happens with
>   conditional requests on methods other than GET or HEAD when the
>   condition defined by the If-Unmodified-Since or If-None-Match headers
>   is not fulfilled. In that case, the request, usually an upload or a
>   modification of a resource, cannot be made and this error response is
>   sent back.

Answer (score 0):

This test script works fine for me. Suspect either useragent or viewportsize

```
casper.options.viewportSize = { width:1024, height: 800 }

casper.test.begin('ZARA', 1, function (test) {

  casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X)');    

  casper.start("https://www.zara.com/us/", function () {
    test.assertTitle("ZARA United States - Official Website");
  });

  casper.waitUntilVisible("#newsletter-subscribe-form", function() {
    this.capture("pass.jpg");
  }, function() {
    this.capture("fail.jpg");
  });


  casper.run(function () {
    test.done();
  });
});
```

[image]